# Package to read in last excel file in a directory in r

Tags: r

I have a directory where all the excel files resides. I want to pick the last file in that directory in r.

Is it possible to achieve the same ?

Comment: What does "last" mean ? Last in lexicographic order? The most recent (last updated) one ?

Comment: lexicographic order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean last in lexicographic order, and assuming that your working directory is set appropriately,

```
ff <- list.files()
lastfile <- ff[length(ff)]  ## or tail(ff,1)
x <- read.csv(lastfile)
```